# Abbyy flexicapture studio regular expressions

Tags: abbyy

does anyone know Abbyy FlexiCapture 12 regex syntax? I need it to accept this type of string (ООО 'Тропик-Юг'). Please help.

('«'|'""')[A-Za-zа-яА-Я_]+('»'|'""')

This is the code I use. It should work logically. I've tried many different ways, but it is not working. It only works if I remove the quotation marks next to the 'or' operation and it works with strings that contain '» This.' But if I leave it as it is now, there is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample:
[а-яА-Я "()'-"]{1-50}

[FLS_RegEx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qODi8.png)